# AngularJS - Display html field content containing ng attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to display a field value that is infact html content with ng attributes. Is there a way to have the content evaluated/executed before displayed?

So how to have **2** as result instead of '**{{1+1}}**'. I'll need to support full html fragments not just angularjs expressions.

```
<script>
   function MyCtrl($scope, $sce) {
          $scope.doShow = true;
          $scope.data = $sce.trustAsHtml('<b ng-show="doShow">{{1+1}}</b>');

   }
</script>
...
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  ..
    <div ng-bind-html="data"></div>
  ..
</div>
```

Comment: try: $scope.data = $sce.trustAsHtml('<b>' + (1+1) + '</b>');

Comment: I extended the code so that you can see the misunderstanding....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [$interpolate](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ng/service/%24interpolate) service to do this. But really think about why this needs to be in the controller and whether there's a way to achieve the same thing in the markup or in a directive...

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $interpolate) {
    $scope.doShow = true;
    var template = '<b ng-show="doShow">{{1+1}}</b>';
    var interpolated = $interpolate(template)($scope);
    $scope.data = interpolated;
});
```

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9g9Ux/)

Comment: Indeed you are right - this way change in model will not get displayed.    I'll go with the directive then. Thank you.